# How to migrate existing application to aurelia-cli?

Tags: aurelia

We have working aurelia based application.

How do we migrate it to use aurelia-cli?

Comment: I'm in the process of doing this, too. I hope some documentation about the cli will appear soon, as I'm just muddling my way through at the moment.

Comment: Actually we did not try to do this ourselvers. I wanted ti check whether some instructions existed before starting migration. If @egeland thinks that this will be documented soon, we will wait for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak to this after doing it myself and being involved actively in another project.  The project I converted was [stamp-web](http://github.com/stamp-web/stamp-web-aurelia) The best way is to take your project

1. Copy it to a backup folder
2. Run "au new" and go through the process of creating your target application and setup the values (ES6, Jasmine etc.)
3. Copy over your src/templates/css piece by piece.  I recommend starting with stuff like helpers, utilities etc. (stuff that has very little dependencies).  As you go bring in the OSS dependencies into package.json as well as modify the Aurelia.json to reference them correctly in the vendor (or other bundle)
4. i18n needs some special configuration (so beware of that) - look to their website or my app stamp-web as an example (I have a bunch of configs that work for various OSS libraries)
5. Keep going as you build up and test your app.

If you look at what I did in stamp-web on the July 16, 2016 commit it will show many of the changes.  I also decided to follow the resource convention for generated objects (like elements, value-converters). This is not needed, and I converted VERY early in the process - as you can see by the date.

Having said all that, I am involved in a much larger project (a corporate affair where we have been working on a large web-app for 10+ months with a team) and porting it over has been painful.  It is likely 3x bigger than stamp-web, but the troubles we have had there is because we have a central "library" of widgets, services etc. as well as build tooling that was used to build apps.  The app conversion was simple, but getting the apps to use the library itself has been a very large challenge.  This is largely because while the CLI seems powerful, we have run into some odd behaviors (we have filed bugs as appropriate) as well as general lack of documentation in regards to the Aurelia.json and require JS syntax.

However, when you get it converted your app will load WAY faster than the SystemJS loaded apps..... it is almost.... impressive how quick is loads.

Initial tracing can be a pain on a large app, however updates and watches are seamless.....

Good luck!